# Python Scrapy Proxies Dead after few rounds?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to build an Amazon Crawler with scrapy.

It worked, but after around 10 Good Proxies every next Proxy get `Proxy <IP:PORT> is DEAD`

I dont understand why...

Thats my Middlewares

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,

    'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
    'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
}
```

I have 1000 Proxies, the most are not dead, there nearly all working on another crawler, but not on amazon after few rounds...

Anyone have an idea?
The User Agent works and the Proxy Rotating also, he show on every next "Dead" Proxy different IP and something

Here is one Log

```
2019-11-06 21:52:40 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <http://XXX:XXX@XXXX:8080> is DEAD
2019-11-06 21:52:40 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/B00VB2ISDM/ref=olp_f_used?f_primeEligible=true&f_usedAcceptable=true&f_usedGood=true&f_used=true&f_usedLikeNew=true&f_usedVeryGood=true> with another proxy (failed 9 times, max retries: 300)
2019-11-06 21:52:40 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Proxy is detected http://xxxx:8080
```

as i said, there mostly working for another site so there not that much dead proxies like it showed on the amazon crawler

I also tried to add that

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 20
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
```

doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

Amazon employs advanced antibot measures.

Use a smart proxy like [Crawlera](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera) or some alternative proxy service that provides good IP rotation and other web crawling features.

Comment: Oh okay, is that free to use? I mean i have my own 1000 proxies

Comment: What is alternative proxy to crawlera?
I mean 150k requests a month is not much for amazon... its done within few hours :/ and other pakets, over 50$ is really high priced